# item decoration not adding margin in item in Gridlayout manager recyclerview

Tags: android, android-gridlayout, gridlayoutmanager, item-decoration

I have been trying to add margin using item decoration in recyclerview item in gridlayout manager.

```
override fun getItemOffsets(
        outRect: Rect,
        view: View,
        parent: RecyclerView,
        state: RecyclerView.State
    ) {

       outRect.set(10,10,10,10)
}
```

but it's not adding margin to the items
What could be the possible reasons that it's not adding margin to grid items?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the margin individually like this.

```
@Override
  public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, 
      RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    outRect.left = space;
    outRect.right = space;
    outRect.bottom = space;

    // Add top margin only for the first item to avoid double space between items
    if (parent.getChildLayoutPosition(view) == 0) {
        outRect.top = space;
    } else {
        outRect.top = 0;
    }
  }
```

also add `clipToPadding="false"` in the XML of the recyclerView

Comment: Hi,
I have tried setting margin individually, still not adding margin.
I am using nested recyclerview.